# Pull out ints out of shuffled NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Alright, I know there are so many duplicated questions asking how to shuffle or randomize an array without any duplicates, but just give this a chance. I already have a shuffled `NSMutableArray`. All that I am trying to do is index a different array with the first three values in the shuffled array.

So lets say that my non-shuffled array consists of 1-10 and the first three values in my shuffled array are 0,5,2. This should give me 1, 6, and 3 when I index. Instead, I receive three numbers like 146945920, 182301921, etc. How do I correctly index an array with the first three values of a shuffled array. Here is my code.

```
    NSUInteger n = [chefLetter[indexPath.row][@"cuisines"] count]; //its count is 3
    NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    //numbers should return something like 0,2,1 

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.count; i++) {
        NSUInteger randomInt1 = arc4random() % [numbers count];
        NSUInteger randomInt2 = arc4random() % [numbers count];
        [numbers exchangeObjectAtIndex:randomInt1 withObjectAtIndex:randomInt2];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",numbers);
    NSUInteger one = (unsigned long)[numbers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)one);
```

Comment: you want a second array that has ordinalities responding to the cardinalities of 1,2,3 in the first array.

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines are the problem.

```
NSUInteger one = (unsigned long)[numbers objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)one);
```

The first line extracts an NSNumber from the array, and converts the *pointer* to that number to an `unsigned long`.  The second line prints the pointer.  What you want is

```
NSLog( @"%d", [numbers[0] intValue] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Array contains objects (NSNumber in your case), not plain int values. You need to get integer values to display them:

```
NSUInteger one = [numbers[0] unsignedLongValue];
```

Comment: shouldn't you use integerValue ?

Comment: It may depend on your case. Probably it would be better to use the same value type you've put in, but -unsignedLongValue will use all necessary conversions in any case

Comment: in 32 bit land NSInteger/NSUInteger are 32 bit types and you will be generating a warning.

Comment: hell yeah preesh brahs